# apt randomly switches languages ever since I installed Arabic on my Pop!_OS running KDE Plasma

Tags: terminal, kde, locale, plasma, language

I recently installed Arabic on my system and since then apt sometimes does things in Arabic and sometimes in English

```
user@pop-os:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                               
Hit:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease
Hit:5 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
قراءة قوائم الحزم... تمّ%              
Building dependency tree... تمّ%
Reading state information... تمّ   
All packages are up to date.
قراءة قوائم الحزم... تمّ0%
Building dependency tree... تمّ%           
Reading state information... تمّ   
حساب الترقية... تمّ%
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 libimage-magick-perl vlc-data libvlccore9 vlc
  imagemagick libavcodec-extra vlc-bin vlc-l10n libavdevice58 libopenexr25
  libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  vlc-plugin-samba libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  libavcodec-extra58 vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16
  libswscale5 libeditorconfig0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-access-extra
  vlc-plugin-skins2 libgsl27 vlc-plugin-video-splitter libswresample3
  imagemagick-6-common vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libgslcblas0
  libvlc-bin vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 سيتم ترقيتها، 0 مثبتة حديثاً،  0 لإزالتها و 0 لم يتم ترقيتها.
```

Sometimes it will even put the Arabic for Hit randomly in between the the English ones (but I couldn't get it to replicate for this post).

I saw some solutions saying that I need to change something with the locale. This is what I get from Locale:

```
user@pop-os:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en_US:en_US:ar
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Finally, this is my system info from neofetch:

```
user@pop-os:~$ neofetch
             /////////////                user@pop-os 
         /////////////////////            --------------- 
      ///////*767////////////////         OS: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64 
    //////7676767676*//////////////       Host: Latitude 5520 
   /////76767//7676767//////////////      Kernel: 6.6.6-76060606-generic 
  /////767676///*76767///////////////     Uptime: 13 hours, 22 mins 
 ///////767676///76767.///7676*///////    Packages: 2983 (dpkg), 52 (flatpak), 8 (snap) 
/////////767676//76767///767676////////   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
//////////76767676767////76767/////////   Resolution: 1920x1080 
///////////76767676//////7676//////////   DE: Plasma 5.24.7 
////////////,7676,///////767///////////   WM: kwin 
/////////////*7676///////76////////////   Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
///////////////7676////////////////////   Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
 ///////////////7676///767////////////    Terminal: konsole 
  //////////////////////'////////////     CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7 (8) @ 4.200GHz 
   //////.7676767676767676767,//////      GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
    /////767676767676767676767/////       Memory: 6696MiB / 23779MiB 
      ///////////////////////////
         /////////////////////                                    
             /////////////
```

How can I change it back to be English only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **LANGUAGE** environment variable is specific to [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Why) (and therefore influences the programs using gettext as a way to ease their internationalization)

You define `LANGUAGE=en_US:en_US:en_US:ar`

As part of which, when the original language is en_US (when the source code is programmed to output some text in English), en_US will not stand as a possible translation per se.
Only the final **ar** will stand as such, this systematically enabling arabic translations **when available** and default to the original language (en_US) when not. (Which BTW left you with the impression of *random switches*)

If you want everything to be displayed in English only, you must remove the trailing *ar*
Note that you could also avoid setting this variable since it will automatically fallback to en_US default.

Care ! If using a DE which might override your login shell settings at launch time, you should prefer select this via dedicated DE tools.
In particular for your KDE-Plasma via system_settings > Regional settings > Language.

Comment: So does that mean that you can't add another language without random things starting to use that language? Since this post, I've noticed other things (e.g. selecting download folder in Firefox) using Arabic. I just want the language to be available, but I don't want it to keep changing a seemingly random things on my system. Isn't there any way to include an extra language without having the system translate to it from time to time?

Comment: @OmarEldahan : There is unfortunately no way to ensure everything will be translated. If selecting french as preferred language… even reading some man page will display only some parts of it in french. Interleaving with original English. Indeed unbearable. Producing translations of each individual message is an independent work managed by the good will of some who just cannot follow the pace of / be in sync with code updates originally en only.